# Notification System

Tags: reactjs

trying to create a notification system which does for example if I click on follow button on someone elses profile, then he/she should be notified when they login to their own profile using React js. Can anyone help me in doing that using Reactjs

Comment: I suggest you hire a freelancer. This website is for help with solving specific coding problems and it helps if you show code you've already written.

Comment: What you did till now? Show your effort

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more details in your question of your problem and better to show what you have achieved so far so people can help you out. Just give you a quick highlight that a real-time notification feature needs both frontend and backend to work together. You can implement ReactJS and Redux to control the state of the notification messages at your frontend.

Here are some tutorials your can follow:

- https://medium.com/jeeon/using-socket-io-in-oder-to-build-a-realtime-notification-system-249a1bfd960d
- https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/notifications-react-and-redux/